# "Engage": ¿Acoplar o engranar?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, educación

I would like to translate "engage" as in

> Engaging in a dialogue

I hesitate to use "acoplando" since I think this has a sexual connotation.  I propose "engranando."  Do you like this?  Do you have a better suggestion?

The context is a scholarly article in the social sciences.

Comment: The question looks right as is. You have a doubt about the proper word to use in a given construction, and you propose some options of your own. Seems like the proper kind of question to post here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stupid me.  It should be

> entablando un diálogo

As offered in a comment, it could also be:

> entrar en un diálogo OR iniciar un diálogo

Comment: Yes, "entablar" seems right. You can say "entablar una conversación" (note the infinitive, better than the gerund if you have no context). You can also say "iniciar una conversación".

Comment: Agreed, as soon as I read the question I was thinking *entablar* along with others like "iniciar/entrar en" maybe even something off the wall like "concertar"

Answer (score 0):

`Engage` can also mean "**involucrar**". It is what I favor for the translation, just because I'm more used to hearing "Engage your customers" which I believe translates as "Involucra a tus clientes".

Can also be used in this context as `Engage (somebody) in a conversation` (Involucra a alguien en la conversación / Involucra a alguien en el diálogo).

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that one.  It sounds a bit weird to my ears (it sounds very... business-speak), almost like *hacer que participe en un diálogo*).  Engaging someone in dialogue in English though could be politico-diplomatic, etc., (e.g. *establecer relaciones por medio del diálogo*) such that simply *enganchar* sounds better to me although a bit informal (y que conste, tampoco me suena bien en este contexto), no?

Comment: @guifa, yes, I probably chose the most "business oriented" definition. I would say that someone might be "*envuelto* en un dialog" but not that "se le *envuelve* en un diálogo". The best translation will probably have to do with context and even verb tense. I picked "involucrar" because I understood that the question suggested "start a dialog with someone" rather than "already be in a dialog"

Answer (score 0):

**Involucrar**.

A situation I'm going through prompted me to look the word "engage" in Spanish, because it best reflects the action I took:

> I no longer want to **engage** in a friendship.

Simple.
Trying to translate this, I got a list of words, including *acoplar*, but none hit it they way I felt it. So I will say:

> *No me quiero **involucrar** más contigo.*

To the point.